# How to configure Exim for autoreplying at domain level

Tags: exim, auto-reply

I have been hunting for an Exim advanced config for a scenario I have.

What would be the best way to achieve an auto-reply at domain level?

For example, there are 2 domains within WHM (domain1.com, domain2.com).

I want to set up an auto-reply for any emails sent to all email addresses under domain1.com whilst leaving domain2.com to operate as standard?

I know the standard config for a system-wide autoresponder would be:

**ROUTER**

```
uservacation:
  driver = redirect
  allow_filter
  hide_child_in_errmsg
  ignore_eacces
  ignore_enotdir
  reply_transport = vacation_reply
  no_verify
  require_files = /var/spool/exim/.vacation.msg
  file = /var/spool/exim/.vacation.msg
  user = exim
  group = exim
  unseen
```

**TRANSPORT**

```
vacation_reply:
  driver = autoreply
```

Is there a simple entry I can make to the Router config to stipulate the domains I want to use the autoresponder?  Such as **domains = domain1.com**?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this personally as when a dictionary attack spammer targets that domain and tries to send hundreds of emails to random addresses (which normally your server would reject with "no such user here" near the start of the transmission- and if you are running something like CSF - will then block them after a number of tries), your server will then receive these emails, process them and then send out autoresponders to the email address featured (which, knowing spammers, will be invalid - and so your server will queue up thousands of auto responses which it'll never deliver...)

However, if you do want to proceed with this, try the following (for *example.com*):

1. First make the auto-responder as per normal in cPanel under "*Tools->Autoresponders*" on a set email address (such as *tester@example.com* )
2. Under "*Tools->Default Address*", set it to

   Send all unrouted email for the following domain: *example.com*

   Advanced Options:

   [select] *Pipe to a program*

   ```
   /usr/local/cpanel/bin/autorespond tester@example.com /home/example/.autorespond
   ```

Where "*tester@example.com*" is the email address you set up in step 1 (it's needed here to be able to point towards the correct autoresponder file and configuration) and */home/example/* is the account directory of the user (whose cPanel username is "*example*")

Alternatively, for step 2:

2. As root, open the file */etc/valiases/example.com* and you'll see something like:

```
tester@example.com: "|/usr/local/cpanel/bin/autorespond tester@example.com /home/example/.autorespond"
*: :fail: No such person at this address.
```

with the * entry being the "default address" setting.
Change the file to be:

```
tester@example.com: "|/usr/local/cpanel/bin/autorespond tester@example.com /home/example/.autorespond"
*: "|/usr/local/cpanel/bin/autorespond tester@example.com /home/example/.autorespond"
```

Hope it helps!